# derived attribute how to identify

Tags: mysql, database-design

I've looked for a while but couldn't come across a decent explanation in order to how to identify a derived attribute from the rest for an example in a scenario if someone could specify with an example that would be very helpful, thank you

Comment: Every attribute except the primary key is a derived attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A derived attribute is one that can be figured out from other information.

An example is "age".  A person's age can be derived from date of birth; a car's age can be derived from date of manufacture.

While "age" is dynamic (it changes over time), derived attributes aren't necessarily dynamic.  If you buy a stock at price X and sell it later for price Y, you profit by Y - X.  Profit is derived from the prices.  The prices themselves, by contrast, usually can't be derived from anything.

Sometimes a derived attribute is looked up, not computed directly.  For example, a car's Vehicle Identification Number encodes various attributes of the car. If you have the VIN and [know how to decode][1] it, it's not necessary to store where the car was built, because that can be derived from the first letter of the VIN.

[1]: https://www.edmunds.com/how-to/how-to-quickly-decode-your-vin.html#:~:text=A%20vehicle%20identification%20number%20(VIN,assigns%20to%20an%20individual%20vehicle.

Comment: really helpful!